# Can I have through Anaconda and another version?

Tags: python, anaconda

I run Python 2.7 through Anaconda. In the last couple weeks I've hit issues with it. Anaconda doesn't play nicely with Django and a virtual environment, and I can't get the Matlab Engine API for Python going with it.

My question is: Could I install Python 3.5 and keep it totally separate from Anaconda? How would I do this?

Comment: What operating system are you on?  Did you choose to use anaconda as the system Python?  Would you be willing to uninstall Anaconda and reinstall it, or do you need to add the new Python while keeping Anaconda completely intact?

Comment: @TheBlackCat I'm using OSX Yosemite, and I'd like to add the new Python and keep Anaconda intact